# Inserting an Alignment Tab with a Leader

Tags: vba, ms-word

I can create an Alighnment Tab with

```
Selection.Range.InsertAlignmentTab Alignment:=wdRight RelativeTo:=wdMargin
```

While the Insert ... Alighment Tab dialog box allows for the creation of a Leader - it would appear the VBE equivalent does not ...

```
Selection.Range.InsertAlignmentTab Alignment:=wdRight RelativeTo:=wdMargin Leader:=wdTabLeaderDots
```

This line produces an error.

Any idea why or how i can get round this?

Thanks, Ken

Comment: You get an error because the `InsertAlignmentTab` method does not have a parameter for a leader. You could use right tab stop instead, or, the best option, use a template that already has the headers formatted to your requirements.